# Apache v7.0.63 phpMyAdmin v4.5.0.1

Tags: tomcat, phpmyadmin

Please let me know that how to config phpmyadmin to apache tomcat server..

I Have done some step..
1 . First download the phpmyadmin 4.5.0.1
2. Extract the folder and copy in the C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.63\webapps\ROOT
3. Then tried to open by web browser with address http://localhost/phpMyAdmin

But it shows 404 error server not found
Although i had defined java-path apache tomcat-path as well
even my localhost:8080 server is running.. when i open localhost:8080 apache server then its run smoothely.

Plz let me know that how to config phpmyadmin with Apache tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

As the name suggest, phpMyAdmin is written in **PHP**, whereas Tomcat is a **Java** servlet container (server). Although [there are methods](http://rdeshapriya.com/running-php-applications-in-apache-tomcat-7/) how to run PHP web applications on Tomcat, but you don't mention you've installed PHP to your Tomcat.

Anyway, I would avoid such hacks if I can. Use Apache HTTPD to run PHP apps.

Comment: as i knew i should copy the folder of phpmyadmin in tomcat's htdocs folder but there is no folder like that in the Apache v7.0.63.. will u please let me understand that how to install phpmyadmin in tomcat v7.0.63.

Comment: As i show in the video there is simple step to configure the PHPMYADMIN with Apache tomcat. I am sending link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KFYXY3MT-XA

Comment: Learn the difference between [Apache HTTPD](http://httpd.apache.org/) and [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/). Use HTTPD server for PHP.

Comment: As i installed Apache2 httpd server for PHP. Then should i remove my older Apache of Java which i already installed?